# Running medium distances with vs. without hydrating

Tags: running, training, hydration, dehydration

For runs up to 10 km, I find I can go without drinking water without significant discomfort. I drink about 750ml beforehand.  After coming back, I'll drink up a good amount of fluids.

Is there an advantage to not regularly hydrating while running short-medium distances? Does it perhaps train the body to make do with less water? Perhaps useful in survival situations?

Or is it strongly preferable to having a few sips every km or so?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6102191/